# Default dictionary value in Swift

Tags: swift

I know I can have a default dictionary value in swift, but I am struggling to do this for a tuple

i.e.

```
var freq = [Int:(Int,Int,Int)]()
```

I want to make a default value

```
freq[num.element, default: (0, num.offset, num.offset) ] = (7, 0, 0 )
```

This produces the frequency table with 7,0,0 for every value when the key does not exist.

Can I use the default for a more complicated dictionary?

For an example if we have an array of numbers [1,2,2,3,3,3]
we can count the number of elements using a frequency table

```
var freq = [Int:Int]()
for num in nums {
    freq[num, default: 0] += 1
}
```

We want to store the initial position of each number, and the final position of each number in the frequency table so use

```
var freq = [Int:(Int,Int,Int)]()
    for num in nums.enumerated() {
        if freq[num.element] == nil {
            freq[num.element] = (1,num.offset, num.offset)
        } else {
            freq[num.element] = (freq[num.element]!.0 + 1, freq[num.element]!.1, num.offset)
        }
    }
```

For this code I want to use a default value.

I am looking for a way of using a default value on a frequency list containing more than just a single value. It is not relevant that I am using a tuple rather than an array of values, for an example I want to find out how to use default with a tuple using arrays.

I tried to use the example above to make a default value, and on testing it does not work. I have looked at previous questions, a Google Search and looked at Apple's documentation.

Question: How to use default for a dictionary var freq = Int:(Int,Int,Int)

Comment: The default value—which is `(0, num.offset, num.offset)`—is never used in the code in your questions. In other words: the code in your question could be written as `freq[num.element] = (7, 0, 0)`.

Comment: It's a frequency table. So traverse a String and count the number of each element. Whether this is used or not, the default is not set.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code that calculates the frequencies. Currently I find it hard to understand what you're asking without the surrounding context.

Comment: It's hugely problematic here, as the minimum requirement is clearly stated. I've given an extended example, but frequently doing so on Stack Overflow gives accusations of "homework" (It isn't) or answering a different question unrelated to the one asked (use an array of values, not a tuple! etc.). This one is wholly about the use of defaults with dictionaries in Swift.

Comment: For what it's worth it's easier to understand what you're asking and what you're trying to achieve after you edited your question to include additional information.

Comment: Still gets downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for? Just get the current value with default value and store it in a variable first makes life easier.

```
var freq = [Int:(Int,Int,Int)]()

var nums = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
for num in nums.enumerated()
{
    let currentTuple = freq[num.element, default: (0,num.offset,num.offset)]
    freq[num.element] = (currentTuple.0 + 1, currentTuple.1,num.offset)
}
print(freq) //output: [1: (1, 0, 0), 2: (2, 1, 2), 3: (3, 3, 5)]
```